# How to include a file from the web in a jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a script I'm testing, which relies on other scripts that are included within the html page header.  When testing a module with jest, these files are never fetched, I was wondering how to include them in the test so my modules have access to the functions they need to run.

example html:

```
<script src="http://example.com/my.js"></script>
```

jest test:

```
jest.unmock('../addeditCreditModal.jsx');
jest.unmock('../../../utils/dataPreprocessor.js');
var $ = require("../../../../../../jquery.min.js");
describe('ADDEDIT', () => {
    const AE = require('../addeditCreditModal.jsx').default;
    const React = require('react');
    const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
    const TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils');

    it('add edit', () => {
        window.$ = require("../../../../../../jquery.min.js");
        //here I need to include a file, bcuase functions will be called when mounting the module, like jquery, which is on my machine, but the web file is not.
        //importScripts("http://example.com/my.js");
        const landing = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
            <AE 
                closeModal={jest.genMockFn()} 
            />
        );
    });
});
```

The java script I want to include is not a module, just generic java script attaching functions to the window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382161/how-to-inject-external-js-from-cdn-to-jest-unit-testing