# How to inject external JS from CDN to Jest unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, npm, jestjs

I have react application with npm and webpack.  I'm trying to add unit testing to it.

I'm using jQuery from CDN included in my index.html rather than using node module.

I'm using jQuery in a Component `Test1` to which I added Unit test cases.

Now, when I'm executing test cases I'm getting error saying

`ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

I understand that Jest is not able to resolve it as I didn't import jQuery import in Component.

Question is, How to let Jest know about external JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can make use of "setupFiles" [configuration](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#setupfiles-array) to allow Jest to execute all scripts / libraries / modules required before start executing tests.

Create and add a file to "setupFiles": ["path/to/setup.js"] and include your library into that.

For example, 

`global.jQuery = global.$ = require('path/to/jQuery')`

Please find my [query](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2043) posted on Jest github repo.

Comment: I guess you could compliment this with some nodejs code that checks if the file is available locally first and downloads it before starting tests. You wouldn't want to have every developer go and manually download the CDN file every time they install...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this. I prefer to use [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/), though you may already be using another bundler like Browserify or Webpack—that should work too. A good quick-start with Require.js is [this](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-cdn) example project. In short, set up Require.js with your CDN files, reference the bundled result in your front-end, hook Require.js into your tests and then `require()` them just as you do your other node modules.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve it using  Webpack as I'm already using it. Also this document says we can run setup files before executing tests. https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#setupfiles-array